# I am not too sure what is going on in this block of swift code. Anyone know how to explain this?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
let interestingNumbers = [
"Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
"Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
"Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
]

var largest = 0
for (_, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
 for number in numbers {
    if number > largest {
        largest = number
    }
  }
}
```

How does this print 25? I am rather new to coding and am still learning so I am trying to get a good handle on how everything works.Could someone please explain this to me?`enter code here`

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is *your* theory of what is happening? Being new to coding, you've probably encountered a `for` loop before -- can you reason what each one does here? Or one of them?

Comment: Add prints: `print("numbers: \(numbers)")`, `print("number: \(number)")`, etc to understand what's going on.

Comment: The code you posted does not include a print statement, so it won't print anything.  Are you missing a final line that prints the result? (largest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is a loop inside another loop (also known as nested loops.)

The outer loop loops through the key/value pairs in a dictionary.

The inner loop loops through the array of integers from the value of each dictionary.

See if you can reason out what the inner code does. It's only a few lines. As Larme suggested, maybe you sould add print statements inside the outer inner loops to log what is happening at each step:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
"Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
"Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
"Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
]

var largest = 0
for (key, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
 print("For key \(key) numbers: \(numbers)")
 for number in numbers {
    print("number: \(number)")
    if number > largest {
        print("Replacing previous largest value of \(largest) with \(number)")
        largest = number
    }
  }
}
```

Then run the program and examine the output carefully.

Comment: Note that one thing may confuse you: `Dictionary`s are unordered collections. The order in which the loop `for (key, numbers) in interestingNumbers ` will return the key/value pairs is undefined. It almost certainly won't be the order in which you define the dictionary, and may change from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops take a long time to read and understand because their possibilities are infinite—you can vary results wildly with subtle changes. Most of the time, when people use a loop, they should reach for premade named tools, which are built on loops. It's a never-ending process, learning those, but it's [axe sharpening](https://amtshows.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Abe-21-1024x706.jpg), allowing you to remove bugs and communicate more effectively.

The name for this code is [`max`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641492-max).

```swift
for number in numbers {
  if number > largest {
     largest = number
  }
}
```

The name for this code is [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap).

```swift
for (_, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
 for number in numbers {
```

Your code is reinventing this wheel:

```swift
interestingNumbers.flatMap(\.value).max()
```

…meaning, "the maximum value found in all of `interestingNumbers`'s values".